# JSON Parser Has Issue With Sql Syntax But Query Works

Tags: sql, json

To start, I had this error:

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value You of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

After some searching, I found a potential solution using substring to see if there were just some phantom characters causing an issue: 'json.substring(3)'

After trying different substring amounts, I got to json.substring(36) and it finally showed me more than 5 letters at a time:

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Expected literal value at character 0 of ; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND from_user = 277976949048048 AND (status = 'pending' OR status = 'accepted'))' at line 2
```

Maybe this new 'expected literal' thing is caused by doing the substring 36, but either way, it seems like there is an issue with my SQL syntax even though I tested it directly with the server and it works perfectly. here is my sql query.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT status FROM users join requests on users.facebook_id=requests.from_user
WHERE (to_user = $id AND from_user = $fbid AND (status = 'pending' OR status = 'accepted'))
OR (from_user = $id AND to_user = $fbid AND (status = 'pending' OR status = 'accepted'))
LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

Any help much appreciated because now I'm officially stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues in the past with parsing JSON files including huge integer numbers.
The number 277976949048048  seems too large to be treated as an integer, I would suggest treating it as a string.